# Как написать правило add_rewrite_rule(); WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, регулярные-выражения

Есть страница на сайте на которой я вывожу объекты, в зависимости от значений в url

К примеру чтобы вывести квартиры в которых 5 комнат:
https://pipl.chaly.xyz/sofia-club-filter/?kolichestvo_komnat=5

Мне нужно чтобы вместо /sofia-club-filter/?kolichestvo_komnat=5, URL выглядел вот так /sofia-club-filter/kolichestvo_komnat-5/

Это возможно сделать?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule там примеры есть

Comment: @KAGGDesign смотрел но в примерах на kama есть только такие варианты

/sofia-club-filter/?kolichestvo_komnat=5  ->  /sofia-club-filter/5/

Это мне не подходит т.к так образом отображается пагинация, мне же нужно чтобы отображалось вот так club-filter/kolichestvo_komnat-5/.

В этом вся проблема(

Comment: с помощью `get_query_var` получаете ваше значение (смотрите примеры которые вам скинули) в котором будет храниться строка типа `kolichestvo_komnat-5` и с помощью регекса вытаскиваете число комнат. Что то типо такого https://regex101.com/r/A3VDhG/1

Comment: @Алексей может я не правильно понимаю, значение у меня 5 по идее мне его не нужно вытаскивать при помощи реуглярного выражения.

У меня проблема создать ссылку чпу.

На данный момент у меня ссылка выглядит вот так /sofia-club-filter/?kolichestvo_komnat=5, а мне нужно чтобы она выглядела вот так club-filter/kolichestvo_komnat-5/.

В примере который скинули выше получается только так: sofia-club-filter/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько это колхозное решение но для меня оно сработало)

При использовании функции add_rewrite_rule()
мы вносим 3 значения.

1: регулярное выражение 
2: передаваемые значения
3: Приоритет    проверки. Может быть top и
  - Элемент списка
      bottom. top - значит это правило будет    проверяться первым.

Исходя из этого:
Если мне нужно сделать из  /sofia-club-filter/?kolichestvo_komnat=5 это  https://pipl.chaly.xyz/sofia-club-filter/kolichestvo-komnat-5/

Я должен написать такое регулярное выражение:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%kolichestvo_komnat%','([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule('^sofia-club-filter/kolichestvo-komnat-([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=sofia-club-filter&kolichestvo_komnat=$matches[1]','top');
```